# NodeMCU default access point name (AI Thinkerxxx)

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, access-point-name

NodeMCU shows a default network as "AI-Thinkerxxx" when it's powered up.

How can I change the default access point name (AI thinker xxx to some other name)?
Where should I make changes to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `wifi.ap.config()`. The sole parameter is a table of configuration details. An example:

```
local cfg = { ssid = 'MySSID', pwd = 'MySecurePwd', save = true }
wifi.api.config(cfg)
```

Full documentation can be found at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/wifi/#wifiapconfig

Comment: I've reason to believe that Sabiha ain't using the NodeMCU firmware but the AT firmware.

Comment: I have designed a development board with ESP8266 chip. By default, it is showing the espressif default access point name(without uploading any sketch). I want to change that name. Do I have to change it in firmware?